# Как затемнить фон страницы при показе диалога?

Tags: gwt, java

Вот так:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ГВТ у ДиалогБокса есть метод setGlassEnabled. Ставь ему true и будет счастье :)

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery руководство по затемнению экрана](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=376)

Comment: Мне интересно, как это сделать с помощью GWT.

Comment: Уточняйте вопрос если вам нужно что-то экзотическое, одних меток недостаточно.